# ObservableCollection DataGrid

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, wpfdatagrid

I bound the ObservableCollection to the dataGrid  itemssource.

the collectionChangedEvent of the observable Collection is getting called only when we add, delete, remove.  But not firing when we update the record.

how to fire the event for Update too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be notified when an item is changed (ie you want to subscribe to this event), you are out of luck with `ObservableCollection<T>` because this collection only fires the `CollectionChangedEvent`.
Indeed, if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you will see changes to the items in the view (WPF does this automatically), but if you need to execute manual actions when an item changes, you can use `BindingList<T>`.

For exactly this scenario I rolled out a custom `BindableCollection<T>`, which implements `ObservableCollection<T>` and adds the `OnItemChangedEvent`. I can provide some sample code if necessary...

Comment: I know it's been over a decade since you posted this answer, but I'm curious to see your implementation. I'm currently struggling to detect changes in the elements of an ObservableCollection myself.

Answer (score 3):

The collection doesn't know when the record is modified. To get a notification when this happens, the record needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`